# What is .stCommitMsg in git global configuration file?

Tags: git

I found this in my git global configuration file `~/.gitconfig`

```
...
[commit]
    template = {my user root folder}/.stCommitMsg
```

I have no idea what is the usage, and also there was no file in this name in my user root folder!

Does any one knows how it works? and is it possible to have a template for git commits?!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You never showed us the actual contents of `.stCommitMsg`, but it is presumably just a Git commit template file.  If you specify this file as a commit template in your global `.gitconfig` then every time you make a commit you should be prompted with the contents of `.stCommitMsg`, asking for a commit message.

Ideally, the template would provide a structure for you to follow while making a commit message.  Commented lines beginning with `#` can help to give hints.  For example, the template might look like this:

```
# enter JIRA issue tracking number

# enter brief description of what was done
```

Answer (score 17):

The `st` in `.stCommitMsg` more than likely stands for SourceTree.

Comment: This seems to be the case. I recently started getting an error "fatal: could not read '/Users/waldyrious/.stCommitMsg': No such file or directory" when trying to commit without passing a message directly in the command, and sure enough, `git config --list | grep commit` did reveal an entry `commit.template=/Users/waldyrious/.stCommitMsg`, which I certainly did not add myself. I wish SourceTree stopped silently messing with my git config :/

Answer (score 5):

I simply deleted the line in my `.gitconfig` file. I believe its set from sourcetree, but i now almost exclusively use cli so its not required)

Follow these steps:

1. `vim ~/.gitconfig`
2. remove line `template = /Users/foo/.stCommitMsg`

Now try commit again, you should have no issue. It will simply use a default commit message.

Personally I only require a commit template following a merge conflict as it fills the commit message with all conflict details. For all other commits I simply use `git commit -m "message here"`

Comment: Or use git to remove the line `git config --global --unset commit.template`